# Jquery set variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have articles
articels are generated while cycle with php.

```
 1 article
     text
   <a href="#">z</a>

 2 article
     text
   <a href="#">z</a>

 3 article
     text
   <a href="#">z</a>
```

If I push link "z" open dialog.

But
I need one thing.
How i can distinguish articles with jquery? Can I take a id php variable and set to the jquery id variable?

**I hope you understand.
Thank's for Answer**

Comment: IDs must be unique you can set it.

Comment: You can wrap a `div` around each article and give it a `id` like `article_[database ID]`.

Comment: I want differentiate articles with jquery. But id article is only in php variable

Comment: Yes, you should give each an id, same way you are giving them values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is couple of ways to attack your problem. The most simple way is to provide the anchor with a unique id to match your article. for example

```
<a id='article_1' href="#">z</a>
```

The second approach is using `data-` attributes.

```
<a data-article-id="1" href="#">z</a>
```

if your triggering a similar event for all three anchors then you can provide a common class name for all anchors

```
<a data-article-id='1' class='link' href="#">z</a>
```

And then in jquery you can capture the click for every anchor as follows

```
$(".link").click(function (e) {
   //then access the unique data attribute within the function
   var article_id = $(this).attr('data-article-id');

   var data = { article_id : article_id };

   $.post("/script/file.php", data, function (data) {} );
}
```

Comment: How i can extract data-article-id with jquery?

Comment: And now If i have variable article_id How i set her to php variable?

Comment: i have this var article_id = $(this).attr('data-article-id'); AND i need  this variable set to php variable. HOW?

Comment: And if i want change variable in the same file (not in /script/file.php ) What i have to do?

Comment: BTW: Thanks for your help is it very useful for me

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to output `<a href="#" id="articleId">z</a>`. You can then use jQuery to open the desired dialog.